# bypasse spamassassin check for outgoing mails: postfix

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

I don't want check my outgoing emails, because we send a lot of API notifications by emails to our clients. I only need check for received mails.

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o content_filter=spamassassin
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o content_filter=spamassassin
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=debian-spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipien
```

This MTA is smarthost for some servers, and they send emails throught it. So, I need to bypass spamassassin check for those servers who are sending email by postfix.

By the way, this MTA is smarthost for some servers, and they send emails throught it. So, I need bypasse spamassassin check for thoses servers who are sending email by the postfix.